# Visual Studio Code PowerShell code debugging from the terminal

Tags: powershell, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have PowerShell script opened in the code window. I am starting the same script from the terminal and expect it to run in the debugging mode. It means: script would stop at breakpoint.

Described behavior would be similar to PowerShell ISE.
However, it runs whole script without stopping at breakpoints.

is there a way to achieve script debugging when started from the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a PowerShell console, you can use this command below to set a breakpoint at a given line of code within your script, then specify the script.  When your script runs, it will break at the given point you requested.

```
Set-PSBreakpoint -Line 9  -Script C:\temp\test_script.ps1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the statement does not start debugging session or at least similar session as one I would start from code window.

Comment: Yes, my solution would have to run independent of the VS console, rather in a PowerShell console window.  Using ISE instead will give you full debugging capabilities, but you will have to manually jump between windows.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **as of v2019.5.0 of the [PowerShell extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), there is *no* support for debugging via an *external* console window.**

A **longstanding feature request** to support this scenario is in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/492), but it has yet to be implemented - I suggest you up-vote the proposal there.
*Update*: I seems that [improvements are now actively being worked on](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/492#issuecomment-518867707).

**Workarounds**, as of v2019.5.0:

**On *Windows*, using an external PowerShell *Core* console ONLY**:

- Open the *folder* in which your script is located for editing, not just the script file itself.
- Switch to the Debug view (View > Debug)
- If the dropdown list in the top-left corner shows `No Configurations`, click on the cog wheel icon to its right:

  - If prompted for an environment, choose `PowerShell`.
  - A `.vscode/launch.json` file is created in your folder with debugging launch configurations that underlie the choices offered in the dropdown list in the Debug view.
- Select `PowerShell Attach to Host Process` in the dropdown list.

Apart from needing to open the entire *folder* in future sessions, the above steps should only be necessary *once*.

To start a debugging session:

Note: Debugging requires the PowerShell Integrated Console to be running, which is currently not automatically ensured. If you activate a PowerShell script in the editor at least once, the PowerShell Integrated Console will be launched, as reflected in the dropdown list showing the active shell in top-right corner of the integrated terminal.

- Press <kbd>F5</kbd> (Debug > Start Debugging).
- You'll be prompted for a target process to attach to: Pick the PowerShell Core session to attach to; all such sessions are prefixed with `pwsh` and show their console-window title as well as the PID (process ID); when in doubt, execute `$PID` in the target console window to determine its PID.
- Pick runspace *1* as the target runspace (even though it says `Busy`).

  - Note: You could skip this step in the future by hard-coding the use of runspace 1 into your launch configuration in `.vscode/launch.json`: Add the following line to the JSON object that defines configuration `"PowerShell Attach to Host Process"`: `"runspaceId": 1`

The debugger should now be attached to your external PowerShell Core console, as reflected in the status output in the integrated terminal.

Note that Visual Studio Code does *not* automatically activate when the debugger hits a breakpoint, and it also doesn't deactivate automatically when execution is resumed - you'll have to manually switch between your external console and Visual Studio Code.

- Switch to the external PowerShell Core console and invoke the script that you want to debug.

  - The *first* time in a session, the debugger will break *right away*, namely at the end of the `PSConsoleHostReadLine` function
  - either start stepping into your script from there, or simply press <kbd>F5</kbd> (Debug > Continue) to continue execution until a previously set breakpoint is hit.
- To stop debugging, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (Debug > Stop Debugging) or press the disconnect icon (depicting a red plug) on the debugging toolbar.

---

**With *Windows PowerShell* / on *other platforms*** the closest you can come with the current capabilities is to use the *integrated* terminal instead, via debug-launch configuration `PowerShell Interactive Session`.

Note: PowerShell Core on macOS and Linux *should* support the debugging technique described above for Windows, but that didn't work for me on my macOS 10.14.6 machine with PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.2; YMMV.

The limitations are:

- No PSReadLine functionality will be available - notably no command recall with the up-arrow key.
- The integrated terminal shares the Visual Studio Code window with the editor windows, so you can't pop out the terminal to a separate window that you could place on a separate monitor, for instance.